# what is the RFC for the BitTorrent protocol?

Tags: networking

Im just looking for the RFC of BitTorrent Protocol. 
I reached to the document [here is it](http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html) but what is actually I want is the number of the RFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually google that.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5694

Comment: RFC5694 is just an RFC which talks about peer to peer architecture in general. It doesn't describe the BitTorrent protocol.

Comment: Funny thing is that this post is now the first result when you do google it, with the actual RFCs directly below it